# Retrieve JSON Value with Jquery for Calculation

Tags: javascript, json

I have a calculation form which gets its values from a JSON

```
    var shirtsJSON = [
        {"pattern": "Delta Adult S/S 5.2oz", "basePrice": 5.68,
            "sizes": {"s-xl": 0, "xxl": 0.84},
            "colors": {"white": 0, "athletic": 0.12, "color": 0.23},
            "numColors": {"1-2": 0, "3-4": 1.60, "5-6": 3.18, "7-8": 4.81, "9-10": 6.39},
            "deductions": {"de48pp": 0, "de72pp": .9, "de96pp": 1.35, "de144pp": 2.37, "de288pp": 2.65},
            "oneLocation": {"onelocnone": 0, "oneloc12": 3.28, "oneloc34": 5.41, "oneloc56": 7.52, "oneloc78": 9.69, "oneloc910": 11.80}, 
            "twoLocation": {"twolocnone": 0, "twoloc12": 3.28, "twoloc34": 5.41, "twoloc56": 7.52, "twoloc78": 9.69, "twoloc910": 11.80},
            "threeLocation": {"threelocnone": 0, "threeloc12": 3.28, "threeloc34": 5.41, "threeloc56": 7.52, "threeloc78": 9.69, "threeloc910": 11.80},
            "fourLocation": {"fourlocnone": 0, "fourloc12": 3.28, "fourloc34": 5.41, "fourloc56": 7.52, "fourloc78": 9.69, "fourloc910": 11.80}},

        {"pattern": "Delta Adult S/S 6.1oz", "basePrice": 6.68,
            "sizes": {"s-xl": 0, "xxl": 0.84},
            "colors": {"white": 0, "athletic": 0.12, "color": 0.23},
            "numColors": {"1-2": 0, "3-4": 1.60, "5-6": 3.18, "7-8": 4.81, "9-10": 6.39},
            "deductions": {"de48pp": 0, "de72pp": .70, "de96pp": 1.25, "de144pp": 2.47, "de288pp": 2.55},
            "oneLocation": {"onelocnone": 0, "oneloc12": 3.28, "oneloc34": 5.41, "oneloc56": 7.52, "oneloc78": 9.69, "oneloc910": 11.80}, 
            "twoLocation": {"twolocnone": 0, "twoloc12": 3.28, "twoloc34": 5.41, "twoloc56": 7.52, "twoloc78": 9.69, "twoloc910": 11.80},
            "threeLocation": {"threelocnone": 0, "threeloc12": 3.28, "threeloc34": 5.41, "threeloc56": 7.52, "threeloc78": 9.69, "threeloc910": 11.80},
            "fourLocation": {"fourlocnone": 0, "fourloc12": 3.28, "fourloc34": 5.41, "fourloc56": 7.52, "fourloc78": 9.69, "fourloc910": 11.80}},
```

Then I have the final results here

```
            $('#48pp').html("Per Piece : " + currency + getMoney(totalPrice));
            $('#72pp').html("Per Piece : " + currency + getMoney(totalPrice));
            $('#96pp').html("Per Piece : " + currency + getMoney(totalPrice));
            $('#144pp').html("Per Piece : " + currency + getMoney(totalPrice));
            $('#288pp').html("Per Piece : " + currency + getMoney(totalPrice));
```

I want it to subtract the values from the deductions JSON I tried doing this:

```
$('#72pp').html("Per Piece : " + currency + getMoney(totalPrice - shirtsJSON.deductions[0].de72pp));
```

but it didn't work and I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you want `shirtsJSON[0].deductions` -- it's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code and JSON.

Comment: Your JSON is not properly formed. See: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [0] is in the wrong place - try it after `shirtsJSON` instead of `deductions`:

```
$('#72pp').html("Per Piece : " + currency + getMoney(totalPrice - shirtsJSON[0].deductions.de72pp));
```

*instead* of:

```
$('#72pp').html("Per Piece : " + currency + getMoney(totalPrice - shirtsJSON.deductions[0].de72pp));
```

This is because `shirtsJSON` is an array, whereas `deductions` not.

**EDIT:**

Quick example of a loop to retrieve multiple `deductions`. This assumes that each `deductions` part contains the same pieces of information each time (e.g. they all contain `48pp`, `72pp` etc.)

```
for(i = 0; i < shirtsJSON.length; i++) {
    $('#72pp').html("Per Piece : " + currency + getMoney(totalPrice - shirtsJSON[i].deductions.de72pp));
    ...etc...
}
```

Notice how the `i` has replaced the `0` in `shirtsJSON[0]`.  You would need to change your code slightly so that it `.append`ed (which adds to the end of whatever's in that element), instead of using `.html` (which overwrites whatever's in that element).

**EDIT 2:**

Here's a link that you might find helpful: http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/

Comment: I have another question about this... If I wanted to have multiple patterns with different deduction that code wont work. Would I need it to be different then? I guess the indexing is whats causing it. I'm still a little new to this so sorry if its a dumb question.

Comment: In your example, `shirtsJSON` is an indexed array (which I'm going to assume represents a single product) containing several associative arrays (which each represent different patterns of the same product).  To get the deductions for each of them, you would loop through the `shirtsJSON` indexed array, probably with a `for` loop, retrieving information about each individual pattern as you go.

Comment: Do you have an example I could see?

Comment: Added an example to the answer

Comment: whenever I added that I couldn't get it to work right. I'll show you my whole code. Maybe something is causing it to break? Heres the [link](https://gist.github.com/1719315)

Answer (score 1):

`shirtsJSON.deductions` is not an array, so trying the index won't retrieve anything.

Try `shirtsJSON.deductions.de72pp` instead, as `de72pp` is a property of the `shirtsJSON.deductions` object.

Also, remove the `[` from the `var shirtsJSON = [{` line.